# HKHealthStore deleteObjects reporting Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=100 "Transaction failure."

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I am trying to **delete** somewhere around **400 objects** in a single go with **HKHealthStore** **deleteObjects** and I'm getting this peculiar error.

> Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=100 "Transaction failure."

Here is the code:

```
self.healthKitStore.deleteObjects(deleteQ, withCompletion: { (success, error) -> Void in
})
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Show code how you delete objects from healthkit

Comment: added the one line...

Comment: What type of objects do you delete? Are they connected like workouts and corresponding samples? Did you create the objects with your own app? Did you select the objects or do you delete them after you created them without selecting?

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, if you are not `requestAuthorizationToShareTypes` before save or delete samples, HealthKit gives you this error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11998104)

Comment: Let’s say, if you want to delete some heart rate samples, you should request authorization before deletion.

let heartRateType = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate)!
        let readTypes = Set([heartRateType])
        
        healthStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(nil, readTypes: readTypes) { success, error in
            self.healthKitStore.deleteObjects(deleteQ, withCompletion: { (success, error) -> Void in
     })
}